# inAppBrowser plugin not working with Phonegap 3.3.0 and iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap Build (with Phonegap version 3.3.0) and I've declared the inAppBrowser plugin in the config.xml file :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

Then I am trying to open a window like this :

```
var clientId = "1039432660734-psg3tpmi0k39csh581c2p8vnqbnkuoq9.apps.googleusercontent.com"; //localhost
var urlAuth = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
        + "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&"
        + "redirect_uri=http://localhost&"
        + "response_type=code&"
        + "client_id=" + clientId;
authWindow = window.open(urlAuth, '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbar=no');     
authWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', parseRedirectUrl);
```

it works on Android, but not on iOS...I don't see the browser coming in, nothing happens....

Can you help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the source file of the plugin (CDVInAppBrowser.m) is added to the section "Compile Source" of your XCode project target, in the tab "Build Phases"

This happen to me recently installing the plugin PushPlugin

There is an issue in cordova marked as resolved but still there are some errors:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4971

-- EDITED --

If this is your error, you should see something like this in XCode's output window:

```
2014-07-04 12:20:20.057 MyApp[2461:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'InAppBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-07-04 12:20:20.057 MyApp[2461:70b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "InAppBrowser1265448945",
  "InAppBrowser",
  "open",
  [
    "http:\/\/www.google.com\/",
    "_system",
    null
  ]
```

]

Comment: thanks for answering but I am not Xcode, I am developping for Phonegap Build directly from Linux. How can I manage the issue in Phonegap Build ? h